# Excel Cell Height Does Not Increase

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to write data into excel cell. The cell has a certain initial height and I'm setting both "merge cell = true" and "wrap text = true".

When the cell content is large, the cell height is not increased. I tried both of the following:

```
_range.entrirerow.autofit() 
_range.columns.autofit()
```

This doesn't work anything for me, please suggest some solution.

Comment: Did you apply it to the top row of the merged cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try _range.Rows.Autofit();

Please note:
COM objects don't get released with double periods. It created tempory variables, which you can't access.

So rather use:

```
Range rows = _range.Rows;
rows.Autfit();
if (rows != null)
{
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(rows);
}
```